# Realtime database add value from dropdown all item at the same time

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, dropdown

I already done one by one add value to realtime database from the dropdown with add button.

here my code for adding a single value

```
private void SaveStudent() {
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("lrn").equalTo(StudentLRN);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Class");
                Query query = databaseReference.child(className).child("StudentLRN")
                        .child(StudentLRN);

                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            autoCompleteSelectStudent.setText("");
                            autoCompleteSelectSection.setText("");
                            textInputLayoutStudent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(TeacherClassroomActivity.this, StudentName + " Already Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Class");
                            databaseReference.child(className)
                                    .child("StudentLRN").child(StudentLRN)
                                    .child("LRN").setValue(StudentLRN);

                            databaseReference.child(className)
                                    .child("StudentLRN").child(StudentLRN)
                                    .child("StudentName").setValue(StudentName);

                            autoCompleteSelectStudent.setText("");
                            autoCompleteSelectSection.setText("");
                            Toast.makeText(TeacherClassroomActivity.this, StudentName + " Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                };
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(TeacherClassroomActivity.this, "No Student Exist in this LRN!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    };
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

[Student list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RZld.png)

and from the image above i want to add all student from dropdown list in one submit button.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: there's no errors on this code, but i want to achieve to add all student from dropdown list in one submit button.